# I have created a calendar help me to save and delete event direction page

Tags: html, redirect, events, database-connection

I have created crud operation calendar using php HTML javascript and have added crud operation to it. When I’m clicking on save event to save data into form on calendar the page is getting directed to another page instead of calendar.php page

I tried changing javascript re linked HTML php and other pages though issue exists

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.